# Meter varios elementos de una tabla en otra en phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo una base de datos para una aplicación que estoy diseñando.
Tengo tres tablas, dietas, comida y alimentos.
Se registran alimentos.
Una comida contiene varios alimentos.
Una dieta contiene varias comidas.

Lo que no sé es como diseñar las tablas y como insertar los elementos para que me permita eso.
Os dejo algunas capturas de lo que tengo y espero haberme explicado bien.

[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]

Edito:

¿Sería así la relación N:M entre comidas y alimentos?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `alimentos` (
  `id_alimento` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `calorias` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `unidades` int(5) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_alimento`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comidas` (
  `id_comida` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nombre` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `receta` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `calorias` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_comida`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `INCLUYE` (
  `id_incluye` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_comida` int(5) NOT NULL REFERENCES `comidas`,
  `id_alimento` int(5) NOT NULL REFERENCES `alimentos`,
  UNIQUE (id_comida, id_alimento),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_incluye`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Mi sql antiguo es el siguiente:

```
    -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.3
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 24-05-2020 a las 18:58:12
-- Versión del servidor: 10.1.35-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 7.2.9

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `nutrilife`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `nutrilife` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `nutrilife`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `alimentos`
--

CREATE TABLE `alimentos` (
  `id_alimento` int(20) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `calorias` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `unidades` int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `alimentos`
--

INSERT INTO `alimentos` (`id_alimento`, `nombre`, `calorias`, `unidades`) VALUES
(1, 'limon', 12, 1),
(2, 'cebolla', 20, 1),
(3, 'pechuga de pollo', 50, 1),
(4, 'cebolla', 20, 1),
(5, 'pechuga de pollo', 50, 1),
(6, 'arroz', 100, 1),
(7, 'macarrones', 26, 1),
(8, 'Aceite de oliva', 200, 2),
(9, 'Sal', 5, 1),
(10, 'Calabacin', 150, 1),
(11, 'Patata', 50, 1),
(12, 'Pimienta', 20, 1),
(13, 'Perejil', 10, 1),
(14, 'Queso', 100, 1),
(15, 'Mantequilla', 300, 1),
(16, 'Queso rallado', 150, 1),
(17, 'Eneldo', 50, 1),
(18, 'Ajo', 10, 1);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `comidas`
--

CREATE TABLE `comidas` (
  `id_comida` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `id_alimento` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `receta` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
  `calorias` int(3) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `dietas`
--

CREATE TABLE `dietas` (
  `id_dieta` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `id_comida` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `dni_paciente` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `dni_profesional` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `tipo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `fecha` date NOT NULL,
  `observaciones` varchar(250) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `pacientes`
--

CREATE TABLE `pacientes` (
  `dni` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `edad` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `altura` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `objetivo` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `peso` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `pacientes`
--

INSERT INTO `pacientes` (`dni`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `direccion`, `correo`, `telefono`, `edad`, `altura`, `objetivo`, `peso`) VALUES
('11111111A', 'Lola', 'Perez Benitez', 'Calle arroz 1', 'lola@email.com', 666666666, 25, 160, 'Perder peso', 85),
('22222222B', 'Pepe', 'Flores Lopez', 'Calle Pera 2', 'pepe@email.com', 222222222, 35, 185, 'Muscularse', 75.6),
('33333333C', 'Maria', 'Garcia Martin', 'Calle Manzana 3', 'maria@email.com', 633333333, 18, 165, 'Evitar el gluten', 60),
('44444444D', 'Lolo', 'Mejias Garcia', 'Calle Chocolate 4', 'lolo@email.com', 644444444, 30, 180, 'Evitar alergeno', 70),
('55555555E', 'Nuria', 'Lopez Gago', 'Calle Limon 5', 'nuria@email.com', 655555555, 19, 162, 'Engordar', 45),
('66666666E', 'Esther', 'Fuentes Rodriguez', 'Calle Naranja 6', 'esther@email.com', 666666666, 45, 170, 'Adelgazar', 90);

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `profesionales`
--

CREATE TABLE `profesionales` (
  `dni` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `direccion` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `correo` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `telefono` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `num_colegiado` int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `profesionales`
--

INSERT INTO `profesionales` (`dni`, `nombre`, `apellidos`, `direccion`, `correo`, `telefono`, `num_colegiado`) VALUES
('12121212A', 'Jose Manuel', 'Sanchez Palencia', 'Calle Termometro', 'josemanuel@email.com', 612121212, 1),
('23232323B', 'Luisa', 'Hernandez Flores', 'Calle Jarabe 23', 'luisa@email.com', 623232323, 2);

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `alimentos`
--
ALTER TABLE `alimentos`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_alimento`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `comidas`
--
ALTER TABLE `comidas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_comida`),
  ADD KEY `id_alimento` (`id_alimento`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `dietas`
--
ALTER TABLE `dietas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_dieta`),
  ADD KEY `id_comida` (`id_comida`),
  ADD KEY `dni_profesional` (`dni_profesional`),
  ADD KEY `dni_paciente` (`dni_paciente`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `pacientes`
--
ALTER TABLE `pacientes`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`dni`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `profesionales`
--
ALTER TABLE `profesionales`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`dni`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `alimentos`
--
ALTER TABLE `alimentos`
  MODIFY `id_alimento` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=19;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `comidas`
--
ALTER TABLE `comidas`
  MODIFY `id_comida` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `dietas`
--
ALTER TABLE `dietas`
  MODIFY `id_dieta` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `comidas`
--
ALTER TABLE `comidas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `comidas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_alimento`) REFERENCES `alimentos` (`id_alimento`);

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `dietas`
--
ALTER TABLE `dietas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dietas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_comida`) REFERENCES `comidas` (`id_comida`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dietas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`dni_profesional`) REFERENCES `profesionales` (`dni`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `dietas_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`dni_paciente`) REFERENCES `pacientes` (`dni`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realmente tu problema es de diseño: has tenido en cuenta únicamente las entidades, no las relaciones que, como son de cardinalidad M:N, no las puedes obviar. Te doy el diagrama ER:

[image: Diagrama ER]

Entiendo que con esta pista lo verás mucho más claro. Si necesitas ayuda para implementar este modelo en MySQL, pídemelo en los comentarios y añade tu dataset en SQL a tu pregunta utilizando modificar y, en phpMyAdmin, Exportar. Con gusto lo añadiré.

**Implementación**

Detallo las instrucciones que modifican el dataset que aportas:

```
ALTER TABLE comidas DROP FOREIGN KEY comidas_ibfk_1;
ALTER TABLE dietas DROP FOREIGN KEY dietas_ibfk_1;

CREATE TABLE contienen(
  id_contienen int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_dieta int,
  id_comida int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_dieta) REFERENCES dietas(id_dieta),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_comida) REFERENCES comidas(id_comida),
  UNIQUE(id_dieta,id_comida)
  );
CREATE TABLE incluyen(
  id_incluyen int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  id_comida int,
  id_alimento int,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_comida) REFERENCES comidas(id_comida),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_alimento) REFERENCES alimentos(id_alimento),
  UNIQUE(id_comida,id_alimento)
  );
```

Las tablas correspondientes a las relaciones `contienen` e `incluyen` registrarán qué comidas pertenecen a cada dieta, pudiendo la misma comida estar presente en varias dietas. Y, de forma análoga, para los alimentos que también estarán presentes en varia comidas. El diagrama de base de datos quedaría así:

[image: Diagrama del modelo físico]

Algo similar te pasará con `profesionales`. Tal y como lo has modelado, cada profesional estaría especializado en una única dieta. Lo cual dependerá de la realidad que intentas modelar.

Además, esto te abre un montón de posibilidades: ahora podrás indicar qué cantidad de un determinado alimento lleva cada comida o cuantas comidas de cada tipo se indican semanalmente para una dieta, simplemente añadiendo un campo.

Fijate en que, según el modelo ER de Chen https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo_entidad-relaci%C3%B3n, SIEMPRE debe haber una `relación` entre dos `entidades`. Otra cosa es que, si la cardinalidad es 1:N, puedas propagar campos que no admitan duplicados a las tablas de las entidades. Que es lo que se hace, entre otras cosas, al pasar del modelo ER al relacional. De lo contrario, te pasará lo que te acaba de pasar a ti: que no hay forma que introducir los datos.

Prueba así y, si tienes dificultad para registrar algún dato, amplía la pregunta y avísame en los comentarios. Ánimo, que casi lo tienes.

**Aclaraciones a los comentarios**

Con respecto a tu consulta, te propongo esta otra forma de hacerla. Es exactamente la misma pero con un SQL menos genérico, más MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM incluyen 
  JOIN alimentos USING(id_alimento)
  JOIN comidas USING(id_comida)
  WHERE comidas.id_comida=2;
```

Sobre añadir atributos, tienes que cambiar la forma de pensar: los campos solamente los puedes propagar a una tabla en caso de una cardinalidad 1:N. En primer lugar cuenta con añadir una tabla de relación. Ya después se verá si puedes eliminarla o no. De hecho, en `comidas` tienes un `id_alimento` que me chirría muchísimo, está pidiendo a gritos un:

```
ALTER TABLE comidas DROP id_alimento;
```

En el caso de los profesionales, dependiendo de quién sea el 1 o la N, el id irá en una tabla o en la otra. ¿Una dieta puede ser asignada a más de un profesional? ¿O un profesional puede prescribir más de una dieta?

Como comentas que cada dieta únicamente puede ser prescrita por un profesional, puedes prescindir de la tabla `prescriben` y propagar el campo `id_profesional` a la tabla `dietas`. Consiguiendo que cada registro de dieta solamente admita un único dato: el profesional que la prescribe y sólo uno.

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda. He modificado mi pregunta para ponerte como creo que podrían ser las tablas.

Comment: Gracias. Tengo insertardos en la tabla alimentos, pacientes y profesionales. En comida y dieta no porque al tener mal las relaciones no sabía cómo hacerlo. Modifico y te pongo el SQL con los insert que tengo.

Comment: @Aerys Acabo de ampliar la respuesta, espero que te resulte útil

Comment: Genial, muy buena la explicación. Lo tengo todo mucho mas claro. He logrado crear comida, añadirle dos alimentos, y los muestro con: 

SELECT alimentos.nombre from comidas inner join incluyen on comidas.id_comida=incluyen.id_comida INNER join alimentos on incluyen.id_alimento=alimentos.id_alimento where comidas.id_comida="2";

Comment: Respecto a lo de los profesionales para que puedan asignar mas de una dieta, y los pacientes tener registraras mas de una dieta, ¿Tendría que añadirles un nuevo atributo en cada tabla, que sea como un contador númerico? Entre dieta y profesional tengo una cardinalidad 1:N

Comment: Gracias ,no sabía esa forma para hacer el select y lo veo más cómodo y rápido de usar. El id_comida y el id_alimento los había borrado. Mi intención a primeras es que 1 profesional puede asignar muchas dietas, por lo que una dieta solo es de un profesional.

Comment: Perfecto, ya lo tienes respondido

Comment: Genial, muchas gracias por la ayuda. Ya puedo empezar a realizar mi aplicación sabiendo que tengo la base de datos perfecta.

Comment: Bueno, bueno... tampoco te confíes, el usuario siempre tendrá alguna sorpresa esperándote :)

Comment: Eso es seguro, ya me saldrá alguna complicacíón lo tengo claro, pero para empezar una cosa básica está bien :)